# In the Json output data fields to remove the leading and trailing quotes of the string array

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, workato

In the Json output data fields the leading and trailing quotes of the string of array type has to be removed. The json data is getting displayed in the workato. We tried with ruby methods like `gsub`, `delete_prefix`, `delete_suffix` but it didn't worked in removing the quotes of the string of array type in workato.

Would someone suggest the solutions to remove the leading and trailing quotes of string array in ruby with workato.

Sample example image of string of array with quotes:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The output `data` hash looks like an array, but with only 1 string `[["a"]]`

It is normal that Workato displays the output enclosed by `"` (double quotation marks), but the real string is only `[["a"]]`

If you insert the `data` DataPill in a Lookup Table, you should not see the double quotation marks anymore